# Same Data applied across all Beans of same type while creating a list of beans with different data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

My use case is to create a List of Beans "B" each having a different instance of a dependent bean "C".

```
@Component("a")
public class A{

    List<B> bPool = new ArrayList<>();
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Autowired 
    A(ApplicationContext appContext){
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        for(int i=0; i<POOL_SIZE; i++){
            bPool.add((B) appContext.getBean("b"));
        }
    }

    //code for multi-threading, which uses beans from the list bPool. 
    //I iterate the list, launch multiple threads, 
    //pass different data to each thread and combine results.
    List<CompletableFuture> multiThreads = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator it = bPool.iterator();
    for(Data d : listOfSomeData){ //same size for listOfSomeData and bPool
        CompletableFuture var = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            B curr = (B) it.next()
            curr.someMethodInB(d);
        });
        multiThreads.add(var);
    }
    multiThreads.forEach(cf -> cf.join());
}

@Component("b")
@Scope("prototype")
public class B{
    //Service class - has some dependencies, like C below
    private C c;
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Autowired    
    B(ApplicationContext appContext){
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        c = (C) appContext.getBean("c");
    }

}

@Component("c")
@Scope("prototype")
public class C{
    //this class holds some data and does some processing on it, 
    //I want this to be different for different instances in different threads.
}
```

While creating list of Bs in bPool, while constructing (I checked by printing in post-construct), a different instance of C is being set for every B respectively.

However, while using the B instances later from the same pool, All the B instances are having the same C instance.

They all have the C instance which was set to the last created B element of bPool.

I am new to springboot and unable to understand this behavior. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show from where and how you are using `B` from bPool.

Comment: @AmitBera added the usage of bPool and its objects. Inside the B's method "someMethodInB", I printed self as well as C instance again, it was a different B instance everytime, but same C instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unsure about what was causing the issue. However a different approach solved my use case.

I went ahead and used the Async functionality provided by spring itself.

Refer: [documentation link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

1. In your main class, Add @EnableAsync annotation and create a pool of background threads to run.

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableAsync
   public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();
   }

   @Bean
   public Executor asyncExecutor() {
       ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
       executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
       executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
       executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
       executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadName-");
       executor.initialize();
       return executor;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Create a new class with a public method with @Async annotation containing the heavy code that we want to run in background. This method needs to be public and has to be in a different class for proxying to work. We cannot create this async method in the same class from where it will be called.

   ```
   @Component
   public class MyAsyncService {

       @Async
       public CompletableFuture<ResultClass> myAsyncMethod(String params){
           //do some heavy tasks here
           return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(instanceOfResultClass);
       }
   }
   ```

   3. Call the above class with async method from a caller class.

      ```
      @Component
      public class CallerService{

          private MyAsyncService myAsyncService;

          @Autowired
          public CallerService(MyAsyncService myAsyncService){
              this.myAsyncService = myAsyncService;
          }

          public void myMethod(){
              CompletableFuture<ResultClass> result1 = myService.findUser("PivotalSoftware");
              CompletableFuture<ResultClass> result2 = gitHubLookupService.findUser("CloudFoundry");        

              CompletableFuture.allOf(result1, result2).join();

              ResultClass finalResult1 = result1.get();
              ResultClass finalResult2 = result2.get();
          }
      }
      ```